# How enable non-sysadmin accounts to execute the "DBCC CHECKIDENT"?

Tags: sql-server

Before each DAO test I clean my database and I need to reset the identity value of some tables. I've created the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SET_IDENTITY
    @pTableName           varchar(120),
    @pSeedValue           int
AS
BEGIN
    DBCC CHECKIDENT(@pTableName, RESEED, @pSeedValue);
END
```

My problem is I need to call this stored procedure with a "normal" user. In order works, This user cannot be member of: sysadmin, db_owner, db_ddladmin.

I've tried with:

a) `CREATE PROCEDURE WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER`

b) `EXECUTE AS USER = 'sa' before call DBCC CHECKIDENT`

But in both cases I got back:

The server principal `sa` is not able to access the database `my_db_name` under the current security context.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Express (64-bit) 11.0.2100.60

Thank you in advance,

Abel

Comment: If your environment permits it, try `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[mydb] TO [sa]` to set the DB owner to something SQL Server can verify (ensure your database doesn't have a group account as an owner by design first!) `EXECUTE AS OWNER` should then work. For a more robust solution, you can use cryptographic signing to give the sproc the necessary permission, but this is [much more involved](http://sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#Certificates).

Comment: Another possible solution, if "clean" means "clear the entire table", is to use `TRUNCATE TABLE`, which as a side-effect also resets the identity and requires only `ALTER` permission on the table. Also consider the use of [database projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh272677) to have a clean, empty database that you can deploy before every test run (or every test, even, but that's probably too slow). Another option is to revert to a [snapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-snapshots-sql-server) or detach/attach an empty DB.

Comment: The specs says you cannot use TRUNCATE TABLE on tables are referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.

Comment: Indeed you can't, so for tables where that's the case, `TRUNCATE TABLE` is not a solution.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Module Signing doesn't need to be super complicated, especially if the permissions are database-level and confined to a single database. Please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44813465/577765) for a 4-step Asymmetric Key-based solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

Caller has to own schema or be **db_owner**:

From doc: [DBCC CHECKIDENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql)

> ## Permissions
>
> **Caller must own the schema that contains the table**, or be a member of the **sysadmin** fixed server role, the **db_owner** fixed database role, or the **db_ddladmin** fixed database role.

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/PDR88437)**</kbd>

Comment: @AbelANEIROS Did you try `CREATE PROCEDURE WITH EXECUTE AS 'user_name'` where 'user_name' owns schema or is db_owner?

Answer (score 1):

This is easy enough to do, but generally speaking you shouldn't *need* to reset identity values each time. Specific identity values shouldn't matter, so the only concern should be potentially reaching the max value due to repeated testing. And in that case I would not recommend resetting each time as it is also a good test to let IDs reach high values so you can make sure that all code paths handle them properly and find areas that don't before your users do ;-).

That being said, all you need to do (assuming this is localized to a single DB) is create an Asymmetric Key, then create a User from it, then add that User to the `db_ddladmin` fixed Database Role, and finally sign your Stored Procedure with that same Asymmetric Key.

The following example illustrates this behavior:

```sql
USE [tempdb];

CREATE TABLE dbo.CheckIdent
(
  [ID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) CONSTRAINT [PK_CheckIdentity] PRIMARY KEY,
  [Something] VARCHAR(50)
);

EXEC(N'
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SET_IDENTITY
    @pTableName           sysname,
    @pSeedValue           int
AS
BEGIN
    DBCC CHECKIDENT(@pTableName, RESEED, @pSeedValue);
END;
');

CREATE USER [MrNobody] WITHOUT LOGIN;

GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.SET_IDENTITY TO [MrNobody];

-------

EXECUTE AS USER = N'MrNobody';
SELECT SESSION_USER AS [CurrentUser], ORIGINAL_LOGIN() AS [OriginalLogin];

EXEC dbo.SET_IDENTITY N'dbo.CheckIdent', 12;
/*
Msg 2557, Level 14, State 5, Procedure SET_IDENTITY, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 30]
User 'MrNobody' does not have permission to run DBCC CHECKIDENT for object 'CheckIdent'.
*/

REVERT;
SELECT SESSION_USER AS [CurrentUser], ORIGINAL_LOGIN() AS [OriginalLogin];

-------

CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY [DdlAdminPermissionsKey]
  WITH ALGORITHM = RSA_2048
  ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'not_a_good_password';

CREATE USER [DdlAdminPermissions]
  FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY [DdlAdminPermissionsKey];

ALTER ROLE [db_ddladmin] ADD MEMBER [DdlAdminPermissions];

ADD SIGNATURE
  TO dbo.SET_IDENTITY
  BY ASYMMETRIC KEY [DdlAdminPermissionsKey]
  WITH PASSWORD = 'not_a_good_password';

-------

EXECUTE AS USER = N'MrNobody';
SELECT SESSION_USER AS [CurrentUser], ORIGINAL_LOGIN() AS [OriginalLogin];

EXEC dbo.SET_IDENTITY N'dbo.CheckIdent', 12;
-- Success!

REVERT;
SELECT SESSION_USER AS [CurrentUser], ORIGINAL_LOGIN() AS [OriginalLogin];
```

Other minor notes:

1. You cannot execute as User = `sa` since `sa` is a Login (server level) and not a User (database level). You can use `EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'sa';` but that then requires `IMPERSONATE` permission and is a security hole since the non-privileged Login can run  `EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'sa'` whenever they want. So don't do that.
2. For variables / parameters that hold names of SQL Server objects, indexes, etc, you should use `NVARCHAR` and not `VARCHAR`. Most internal names use `sysname` which is a system alias for `NVARCHAR(128)`, so `sysname` is usually the preferred datatype.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! "You shouldn't need to reset identity values each time" - true, but in my case, the range of INTEGER data type may be used up if I don't reset the identity. I don't want to go and increase the table storage by changing it to BIGINT.