# PUT parameter into IDENTITY(1,1) property in SQL Table Creation script

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I would like to set custom Identity with parameters. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Pets (
    PetId int IDENTITY(@Parameter,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    PetName varchar(255)
    );
```

My SQL parser does not accept such syntax.

Comment: No, it doesn't, because `IDENTITY` must be defined with a literal. Why do you want the seed to be parametrised? This feels like an [XY problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: Why aren't you using `NOT NULL`?

Comment: Most DDL commands allow no kind of parameterization whatsoever. You'll need to build the command dynamically, or (if using SSMS) create a [template](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/ssms/template/templates-ssms) with parameters that you can then complete with Ctrl-Shift-M.

Comment: You could also use Dynamic-SQL to set the literal value if you're desparate - but normally you'd use `DBCC CHECKIDENT`.

Comment: @Dai for the ID column the PRIMARY KEY makes it so. For the other column, agreed, but hopefully they just simplified the script

Comment: @AaronBertrand On the subject of data-modelling, I noticed they're using `varchar` when they probably should be using `nvarchar` as pets' names are rarely ASCII-safe... and, [uh-oh](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)... (well, pet-names)

Comment: @Dai if you think the only problems in their data model are exposed by this one `CREATE TABLE` statement...

Comment: Please read the [tag:sql] tag wiki. You shouldn't be using it with a tag for a specific DBMS' tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you do need to use a literal integer (or none at all) with `IDENTITY` in `CREATE TABLE` statements, you can reset the `IDENTITY` seed value after you've created the table using `DBCC CHECKIDENT` which *does* support parameters.

Also:

- When working with SQL Server you should always fully-qualify object names with their parent schema (the default is `dbo`), otherwise objects might be created in a different schema and names won't be resolved when addressed from objects in other schemas (it helps performance too).
- Also, here's some unsolicted database design and data-modelling pointers:

  - Generally speaking, all columns should be `NOT NULL` unless you're absolutely certain otherwise.

    - *Especially* for textual columns: there's nothing quite as annoying as having to deal with a textual column containing both `NULL` and blank `''` values and no clue about if there's any semantic difference between the two.

      - Bonus bingo: if the column also contains non-empty but whitespace strings. This is what `CHECK` constraints are for, folks!
  - Also, *annoyingly*, if you don't specify either `NOT NULL` or `NULL` in a `CREATE TABLE` column specification then SQL Server defaults to assuming `NULL`.
- Names, or really any textual column containing *human-readable text* should generally be `nvarchar` and not `varchar`.

  - This doesn't apply to other RDBMS where their `varchar` types natively support Unicode.
  - The exception to this is when using SQL Server's oddly-implemented support for UTF-8, but that's another discussion.

Anyway, like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Pets (
    PetId   int           NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    PetName nvarchar(255) NOT NULL
);

GO

DBCC CHECKIDENT ( dbo.Pets, RESEED, @newIdentitySeed );
```

- The `GO` statement is for the benefit of SSMS; if you're using this from program code you might need to move the `DBCC CHECKIDENT` command to a separate command-batch.

**Important caveat about permissions**:

- I assume people would want to run `DBCC CHECKIDENT` to reset a table's state for running automated integration tests or some other dev/test scenario where they have `sysadmin` or `db_owner`-level permissions, in which case there's no problem.
- But if you don't have `sysadmin` (Server-level), `db_owner` (DB-level), or `db_ddladmin` (DB-level) permissions then you won't be able to use `DBCC CHECKIDENT`, even though you *can*  create a copy of the table, `DROP TABLE` the original table and recreate it with as new `IDENTITY` from a literal - which is just silly.

  - In that case, ping your sysadmin for assistance and [show them this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44526946/how-enable-non-sysadmin-accounts-to-execute-the-dbcc-checkident).
  - Also, see the notes from Aaron in the comments for this answer.

Comment: "Annoyingly, if you don't specify either `NOT NULL` or `NULL` in a `CREATE TABLE` column line then SQL Server defaults to assuming `NULL`." Even more annoyingly the story is actually far more complicated than this and governed by no less than three separate settings -- `ANSI_DEFAULTS`, `ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON` and `ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF`. The moral of the story is to always explicitly specify nullability since the default is *configurable*, even though (due to the way clients work) you will *usually* get a `NULL` default.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Microsoft's been saying they'll change the defaults for `ANSI_DEFAULTS` (meta...) to be more standards-compliant for decades now - I don't know if I should still hold hope or not.... On a related note, I think it's now been 18 years since they obsoleted `text` and `ntext`, but they're still first-class types in SQL Server 2022. _le sigh_.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I really need this method to reseed the table identity. It work for me.

Comment: (A potential complication for future readers is that applying `DBCC` after the fact requires different permissions than the initial `CREATE TABLE`.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand The docs say that `DBCC CHECKIDENT` can be used by the user that owns the table - presumably the creator of the table also owns it, no? **UPDATE:** Oh, lol - wow, [that documentation is wrong and people have been complaining about it for years now](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c883e504-2452-4d33-8922-f87cbb34b46e/dbcc-checkident-permissions?forum=transactsql)... Looks like the user needs to be in the `db_ddladmin` role - while (confusingly) `CREATE TABLE` uses `GRANT CREATE TABLE` - that's confusing.

Comment: @Dai [Current docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql) say `Caller must own the schema that contains the table, or be a member of the sysadmin fixed server role, the db_owner fixed database role, or the db_ddladmin fixed database role.`

Answer (score 3):

You can use dynamic SQL but this doesn't seem right.

```
DECLARE @Parameter int = 1000;

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'CREATE TABLE dbo.Pets 
  (
    PetId int IDENTITY(' 
      + CONVERT(varchar(12), TRY_CONVERT(int,@Parameter)) 
      + ',1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    PetName varchar(255)
  );';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: If `@parameter` is already `int`, why use `TRY_CONVERT`?

Comment: @Dai I don't know that `@Parameter` is `int`, I had to guess. This makes sure that if they're passing this in as a string it will render the entire statement `NULL` if it isn't an integer.

Comment: Plus, as an added bonus, means that *if* `@Parameter` was incorrectly defined as a string based data type, the failed conversion would stop any injection attempts.